# Cannot set the value of read-only property 'outputFile' for ApkVariantOutputImpl_Decorated{apkData=Main{type=MAIN, fullName=debug, filters=[]}}

Tags: android

After the Android Studio Update, there is error as below image,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DN3Bc.png)

here project build.gradle code,

```
debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                output.outputFile = new File(
                        output.outputFile.parent,
                        output.outputFile.name.replace("app-debug.apk", "GoodWeather-debug-${variant.versionName}.apk"))
```

Answer (score 0):

> #### Modifying variant outputs at build time may not work
>
> Using the Variant
>   API to manipulate variant outputs is broken with the new plugin. It
>   still works for simple tasks, such as changing the APK name during
>   build time, as shown below:
>
> ```
> // If you use each() to iterate through the variant objects,
> // you need to start using all(). That's because each() iterates
> // through only the objects that already exist during configuration time—
> // but those object don't exist at configuration time with the new model.
> // However, all() adapts to the new model by picking up object as they are
> // added during execution.
> android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
>     variant.outputs.all {
>         outputFileName = "${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
>     }
> }
> ```

Source: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html